# Enable Remote Connections on Windows Server 2012 via AWS User Data Field

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I was working on an AWS EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012 via RDP when I accidentally disabled "remote connections" under "Advanced system settings", which immediately closed my RDP session.

Is there any script I can put into the EC2 "User Data" field that will re-enable remote connections when I reboot the instance?

If not is there any way to re-enable it by mounting the drive under another instance?

Thanks

Comment: Did you start the server using Cloud Formation and have cfn_hup running?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing the following:

> Stop the instance, detach the root volume and attach it as another partition on another Windows instance. Once attached, go to disk management and set it online, mount the registry hive and make the proper changes.
>
> Navigate to the following location in the registry
>
> > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
>
> In the right pane, locate a REG_DWORD value named fDenyTSConnection. Double-click on fDenyTSConnection and change the value data from 1 (Remote Desktop disabled) to 0 (Remote Desktop enabled).
>
> If the server was placed in drain mode, then locate a REG_DWORD value named TSServerDrainMode and change the value data from 1 (Remote Desktop disabled) to 0 (Remote Desktop enabled).
>
> Unmount registry, set the disk offline, detach EBS volume, and attach it back as the root volume of the original Windows instance and verify if you can access this now.
>
> Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128525

See also:

> How to mount a registry hive in Regedit
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuSxbDIlFW0

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, You can able to re-enable RDI using run the AWSSupport-ExecuteEC2Rescue Automation (AWS Systems Manager)

**Please follow below steps carefully:**

1. Open the AWS Systems Manager console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Automation**.
3. Choose **Execute automation**.
4. In the documents list, choose **AWSSupport-ExecuteEC2Rescue**. The document owner is Amazon.
5. In the Document details section verify that Document version is set to the highest default version. For example, 13 (default).
6. In the Execution mode section, choose **Simple execution**. Leave the Targets and Rate Control option disabled.
7. In the Input parameters section, specify the following parameters:

   For UnreachableInstanceId, specify the **ID of the unreachable instance**.

   For LogDestination, specify an Amazon S3 bucket if you want to collect operating 
   system-level logs while troubleshooting your instance. Logs are automatically uploaded 
   to the specified bucket.

   For EC2RescueInstanceType, specify an instance type for the EC2Rescue instance. The 
   default instance type is t2.small.(Please leave as it is if you are confused and go 
   ahead)

   For SubnetId, specify a subnet in an existing VPC in the same availability zone as the 
   unreachable instance. By default, Systems Manager creates a new VPC, but you can 
   specify a subnet in an existing VPC if you want. (Please leave as it is if you are 
   confused and go ahead)

**Note**

If you don't see the option to specify a bucket or a subnet ID, verify that you are using the latest Default version of the document.

For AssumeRole, if you created roles for this Automation by using the CloudFormation procedure described earlier in this topic, then specify the AssumeRole ARN that you copied from the CloudFormation console.

8. Choose Execute automation.

It takes sometimes (5-10 minutes) and you are able to access your old instance with new IP.

Here is the AWS documentation for this issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connection-ec2-windows/